# Only 'atomic' vectors as part of the base of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given a vector subspace    $U_1=${$\left(\begin{array}{c}
>         \lambda+µ \\
>         \lambda \\ µ
>       \end{array}\right)\in R^3$: $\lambda,µ \in R$ }
>
> Determine a possible base of this vector subspace.

As far as I know, the base of a vector space is a number of vectors from which every vector in the given vector (sub-)space can be constructed.

My suggestion for a base of the given vectorspace would be:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
       \lambda \\
       0 \\ 0
     \end{array}\right)+
\left(\begin{array}{c}
       µ \\
       0 \\ 0
     \end{array}\right)+
\left(\begin{array}{c}
       0 \\
       \lambda \\ 0
     \end{array}\right)+
\left(\begin{array}{c}
       0 \\
       0 \\ µ
     \end{array}\right)
$$

None of these vectors can be written as a linear combination of  the other vectors.

What also came to my mind as a possible solution was:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
       \lambda+µ \\
       0 \\ 0
     \end{array}\right)+
\left(\begin{array}{c}
       0 \\
       \lambda \\ 0
     \end{array}\right)+
\left(\begin{array}{c}
       0 \\
       0 \\ µ
     \end{array}\right)
$$

Which - if any - of these two is a valid base for the given vectorspace? Is the second one invalid, because it can be written like the first one?

Comment: Neither. Your vectors aren't even elements of $U_1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\{\left(\begin{array}{c}    \lambda+\mu \\     \lambda \\ \mu    \end{array}\right)\in \mathbb{R}^3: \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}\}=\{\lambda\left(\begin{array}{c}   1 \\     1 \\ 0    \end{array}\right)+\mu \left(\begin{array}{c}   1 \\     0 \\ 1    \end{array}\right)\in \mathbb{R}^3: \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Does that help?

Note that all linear combinations of vectors in your base need to be contained in the subspace.

Comment: Is that how it's done? Finding n vectors where n is the dimension of the given vector space - 1 that, multiplied with different scalar result in the original vector describing the vector subspace?

Comment: @Rickyfox I think you didn't understand the concept of vector spaces yet. They can be described by a set of fixed vectors, usally not just one, with the property that every multiple of the vector is contained in the vector space.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to know is that a subspace's dimension cannot exceed the containing space's dimension. Since the number of vectors constituting a base is equal to the dimension, your first suggestion is wrong, as it suggests that the subspace is of dimension 4 in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is only of dimension 3.

Then, if a subspace's dimension is equal to the dimension of the containing space, they are equal. This means that if your second suggestion is correct, the subspace $U_1$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is also false (take for instance the vector $(1,0,0)$)

As a general rule, you need to factor the scalars appearing in the definition (here $\lambda$ and $\mu$), like Listing suggested, and the basis will naturally appear.